# Step size for controlling stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I am using a PK243 - 03A unipolar stepper motor, its step angle is 1.8 degrees. I am planning to step the motor periodically on it's starting frequency which is coming out to be 1.3kHz, to see how it makes 200 steps per revolution, what I cannot decide is the step size of the pulse. How long should be the pulse high to get 1.8 degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pulse duration is irrelevant. It's the number of pulses that matter.

In this case, you need 200 step cycles per revolution. You derive the pulse duration from how rapidly you want to step.

I'm assuming you are using a driver IC, which takes step/direction pulses. If you're driving the motor directly, things are more involved.

Comment: No I am not using a driver IC, i made a driver myself with a bunch of mosfets and bjts. You mean there is no criteria for  pulse width? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The pulse width is just how long you want to dwell at each step. If you want to stop, you just keep the last energized winding energized. You need to stop thinking of the individual steps as "pulses". They're steps. If you stop stepping, you don't turn off the outputs, you just stop changing them.